# How to include the employee's multiple work hours with dates on the task using vsto add-in for microsoft project

Tags: c#, vsto, project-management, ms-project

In my vsto add-in for Microsoft Project, following code is not including the all work hours which i have defined at variable 'entryDates'. Because, Inside the loop, existing assignment is updating with new start, finish, and work hour instead of including new.

**How to include the employee's multiple work hours with dates on the task?**

```
Project project = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
project.DefaultTaskType = PjTaskFixedType.pjFixedWork;

Task testTask = project.Tasks.Add("Test Task");
Resource resource = project.Resources.Add("Sridhar Netha");
Assignment newAssignment = testTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);
var entryDates =new List<EntryDate>(){
    new EntryDate{ DateEntered=DateTime.Parse("2023-09-05"), Hours=(decimal)2 },
    new EntryDate{ DateEntered=DateTime.Parse("2023-09-12"), Hours=(decimal)5 },
    new EntryDate{ DateEntered=DateTime.Parse("2023-09-19"), Hours=(decimal)4 }
};
foreach (EntryDate entryDate in entryDates)
{
    newAssignment.Start = entryDate.DateEntered;
    newAssignment.Finish = entryDate.DateEntered;
    newAssignment.Work = entryDate.Hours+"h";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudo code to add work hours to an assignment:

```
TimeScaleValues tsvs = newAssignment.TimeScaleData("2023-09-05", "2023-09-20", pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, pjTimescaleDays);
foreach TimeScaleValue tsv in tsvs
{
    /* check to see if tsv.StartDate is a date in the EntryDate list and if so,
       add the hours using the Value property */
};
```

**Note 1:** The date arguments of the TimeScaleData method are date/time values so an EndDate of 9/19/23 would be midnight and therefore leave no working time on that date. Therefore, add a day to the end date to get a full working day as expected.
E.g. TimeScaleData("10/2/23", "10/5/23") yields an array of 3 days: 10/2, 10/3, 10/4.

**Note 2:** Work is stored in minutes, so multiply hours by 60.

Solution:

```
Project project = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
project.DefaultTaskType = PjTaskFixedType.pjFixedWork;

Task testTask = project.Tasks.Add("Test Task");
Resource resource = project.Resources.Add("Sridhar Netha");

Assignment newAssignment = testTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);

var entryDates =new List<EntryDate>(){
    new EntryDate{ DateEntered=DateTime.Parse("2023-09-05"), Hours=(decimal)2 },
    new EntryDate{ DateEntered=DateTime.Parse("2023-09-12"), Hours=(decimal)5 },
    new EntryDate{ DateEntered=DateTime.Parse("2023-09-19"), Hours=(decimal)4 }
};
/*foreach (EntryDate entryDate in entryDates)
{
    newAssignment.Start = entryDate.DateEntered;
    newAssignment.Finish = entryDate.DateEntered;
    newAssignment.Work = entryDate.Hours+"h";
}*/

DateTime startDate = (DateTime)entryDates.Min(x => x.DateEntered);
DateTime endDate = (DateTime)entryDates.Max(x => x.DateEntered);

TimeScaleValues tsvs = newAssignment.TimeScaleData(startDate.Date, endDate.AddDays(1).Date, PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays);
foreach (TimeScaleValue tsv in tsvs)
{
    // check to see if tsv.StartDate is a date in the EntryDate list and if so, add the hours using the Value property 
    var entDate = entryDates.Find(f => f.DateEntered.Value == tsv.StartDate);
    if (entDate != null)
    {
        var minutes = entDate.Hours.Value * 60;
        tsv.Value = minutes;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I am getting an error `The argument value is not valid.` when I try to add work hours for `Weekends`, `Holidays`. There is no issue when adding work hours for regular working days. **How to handle this situation? The Weekends or Holiday work hours should consider as `Overtime`.**